# Spring compressed between two blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I´m trying to solve this problem and I don't understand it well.

We have a block whose mass is $m_2$, a block whose mass is $ m_1$, and a spring of length $8a$. If you connect the blocks like this:

```
m1
v
v
v
v
v
v
m2
```

The spring will be compressed, so its length will be only $7a$. Then you compress it even more to the length $4a$. You should then show that if $m_2<2 m_1$, the lower block will lift off from the floor.

Well, I can find the spring constant, but I´m not sure I understand what will happen. I suppose that the maximal amplitude will be $10a$ and that is when the upper block reaches this amplitude, the lower one should lift off.

So, we need that the force in the position of maximal amplitude (let's call it A) be more than $m_1 g + m_2g$. However, I thought that there is also the force of the spring, which should have the same direction as both gravity forces in that position A, but that just doesn't make sense.

I feel it should be like this, however, I don´t understand the forces in it and if it is connected also with some energy.

Comment: Your supposition about the maximal amplitude is correct. Forget about the complete system, and concentrate only on m2. What are the forces on m2 at the maximum amplitude? Under what conditions m2 will lift off?

Comment: I think that besides gravitional force (which is m2*g) there is some force of the spring, of course. This one has the opossite direction than gravitional one, because it is orientated to the state of equilibrium. So when this force of spring is bigger than m2*g, the m2 should lift off.

Comment: Sure. So, you have just to evaluate the force of the spring: this one is stretched by 2a, and you know how to evaluate the spring constant.

Comment: And how to determine the force of spring: At first, it seemed to be logic to me that it could be 4a*k; I thought so because the state of equilibrium was in 7a, so it should be 7a, but there was another block m1, which was in the maximal amlitude, so because of it there was another force of spring = -3a. So together, it was 4a. But if I think about it, it doesn´t make a sence... but I don´t know why...

Comment: The force of the spring does not depend about its state of equilibrium, it is simply k*d where d is how much it is stretched. Remember that "the force of the string" is the force that the spring is applying to m2.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! That was the problem, that I didn´t unterstand what exactly the force of the spring means. Maybe I will think about it a little bit, but I think that now it´s  clear to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have "done the work" (as much in the comments as in the original question...) but are left with a small uncertainty about the concept of what force applies where, I feel I can now write an actual answer.

The following diagram explains it (gravity operates from right to left in my picture so the text aligns better):

[image]

The spring compresses by $(8-7)a = a$ when a force of $m_1 g$ is applied. We conclude that the spring constant $k = m_1 g / a$.

From this equilibrium position, the top mass will move symmetrically with respect to the $7a$ position as long as $m_2$ stays on the ground. Thus, when it has been compressed to $4a$ (a deflection of $3a$) it will oscillate with an amplitude of $3a$, reaching a maximum extension of the spring of $(7+3)a = 10a$.

At this point, the spring has been stretched by $(10 - 8) a = 2a$ (remember the unstretched string had a length of $8a$). And the force it exerts on $m_2$ is therefore

$$F_2 = k x = \frac{m_1 g}{a} (2a) = 2 m_1 g$$

That is a force that is just enough to pick up a mass $m_2 = 2 m_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Originally, I had a problem that I didn´t understand well what exactly mean the force of the spring and how it apllies to m2. So it was really helpful for me that I have found and understood it before reading your answer, however, this makes it even more clear, thank you very much for your time and for your answer.

Comment: @David28 I would not have written the answer if you had not first spent time figuring it out yourself. You learnt more this way but now the solution is there for future users struggling with similar concepts.